# In Rails when using AJAX, how to change the js file it loads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

For example, I use data remote for the pagination like this :

```
<%= paginate @products, :remote => true %>
```

It works. But the problem is I have multiple lists to paginate in one page. So, I need a way to send the call to a separate files so I can render the appropriate content. How can I do this?

My index.js.erb :

```
<% if params[:list] %>
   $('#products').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@products) %>');
   $('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@products, remote: true, param_name: 'list' ).to_s) %>');
<% end %>
```

Comment: I believe you are talking about different js view template. If so you can do something like this. 
if request.xhr?
      render(
        :partial => "partial_name",
        :locals => {:products => @products},
        :layout => false
      )
in the controller's action.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to add another param with paginate.

```
<%= paginate @products, :remote => true, :param_name => param_name %>
```

This params name will pass as parameter to controller so you can control which ajax pagination you are calling.

If you are calling same action then on the basis of param name you can change the value of `@products` also. One more thing you need to consider in your `xxxx.js.erb` file you need to render paginate object also.

In your js file you can change html on the basis of param also.

```
- if params[:xxx]
  $('#xxx').html('#{escape_javascript render(:partial =>"partial_name",:locals => { :posts => @products, :param_name => 'xxx'})}');
  $('#xxx #paginator').html('#{escape_javascript(paginate(@products, :remote => true, :param_name => 'xxx').to_s)}');
- if params[:yyy]
  $('#yyy').html('#{escape_javascript render(:partial =>"partial_name",:locals => { :posts => @products, :param_name => 'yyy'})}');
  $('#yyy #paginator').html('#{escape_javascript(paginate(@products, :remote => true, :param_name => 'yyy').to_s)}');
```

In your controller you should use `param_name` instead of params `page`

Comment: Thanks. How can I call different js from controller

Comment: Are you calling different action

Comment: You can do it in same js file on the basis of params_name.

Comment: Now it's working except for the first page. I can go to other pages but can't come back to page 1

Comment: I posted my index.js.erb. When i remove the if, it works. But can't remove it

Comment: It should work with `if` also. try check with `present?`. `<% if params[:list].present? %>` It should work with if.

Comment: Try add alert inside if block and see if alert popup or not

Comment: I think ruby code is not running in that file. Is there a way to pick the file to load from the controller?

Comment: in responds_to block add if case and using format.js render particular js file on the basis of params